# How to stop a Spark Job Execution programatically

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

If I want to stop my Spark Application from inside the spark job in a programmatic way in case of Exceptions or Specific use cases , how to acheive this from Java Code .
I tried to call JavaSparkContext.close() but still the job seems to be running .

Comment: do you found any solution?

Answer (score 4):

You can use following methods to cancel the running spark job :

`cancelJobGroup(String group Id)`- Cancel active jobs for the specified group.
`cancelAllJobs()` - Cancel all jobs that have been scheduled or are running.

For more details, you can refer the [API doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#cancelJobGroup(java.lang.String))